# html id/class first symbol digit, is valid?

Tags: html

In HTML, what characters are valid as the first character in an `id` or `class` attribute?

For example, is `<div id="4bla"></div>` valid or must they start with only letters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HTML5:**

As of HTML5, it is indeed valid to start an ID with a digit.

In HTML5, even this is valid:

```
<p id="#">Foo.
<p id="##">Bar.
<p id="♥">Baz.
<p id="©">Inga.
<p id="{}">Lorem.
```

As is your example:

```
<div id="4bla"></div>
```

**Note:** It may be valid in HTML5, however **it is not valid in CSS**.

That means `<div id="4bla"></div>` is valid, but `#4bla { background-color:red; }` isn't.

Start ID's with characters instead for maximum compatibility.

**HTML4:**

It is invalid if you're still using HTML4:

> "ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."

Comment: Was it invalid before HTML5? Also, could it cause any issues with CSS and are there any browser specific issues with it?

Comment: @neelsg Yeah, it was invalid before. Here, check this - http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @neelsg It was invalid in HTML4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: @Zenith I guess it is still invalid to start an id with a number, yes, even in HTML5

Comment: I didn't vote anything up. For a question like this I would like to see a comparison of compatibility between XHTML, HTML5 and HTML4 as well as different browsers and any other implications such as CSS. For instance, would an id starting with `#` work in CSS etc.

Comment: @Mr.Alien No it's not...

Comment: @Zenith Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/y2hXT/

Comment: @Mr.Alien CSS != HTML. It is valid in HTML5 but not in CSS.

Comment: @Zenith Can you provide me any documentation link? Cuz I think you've picked that thing from here http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @Mr.Alien See the links posted by TJ here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5672936/1586880

Comment: @neelsg It doesn't, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, its not XHTML valid.
You can use the [XHTML-Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) to check your HTML code.

[image: XHTML Validator Image]

**But even if its not XHTML-Valid it should work in almost every browser.**

Comment: I've never heard of XHTML 4.01.

Comment: Check out the W3C XHTML validaror??? http://validator.w3.org