# Can I use an anchor ID starting with a number in HTML5?

Tags: html, numbers, anchor

Can I use an anchor ID starting with a number in HTML5?

```
<a id="1" class="anchor"></a>
```

I was told this was a NO NO. But it seems to work fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome. So, what gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it valid to start an ID with a number in HTML5? Do other technologies support these id's if we are using HTML5 doctype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853999/is-it-valid-to-start-an-id-with-a-number-in-html5-do-other-technologies-support)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly valid in HTML5.

> #### *3.2.3.1 The `id` attribute*
>
> The [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) attribute specifies its element's [unique identifier (ID)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-id). [[DOM]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsDOM)
>
> The value must be unique amongst all the [IDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-id) in the element's [home subtree](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#home-subtree) and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
>
> > **Note:** There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, **IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit,** start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute (emphasis added)