# CSS can't select classes/id's with numbers in it?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why can't you use numbers in CSS and is there another way of doing the job? I have the following code:

```
<div class="center 400-width" id="position">
    <div class="" id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="" id="content">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="" id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS selects the class `400-width` which means the container gets a width of `400px`. And the `background-color` is for checking if it's true.

```
.400-width{
    width:400px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

It doesn't happen right now as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gekkeabt/XQjE4/1/)

I solved the problem by replacing `400-` by `four`. So it becomes `fourwidth`.

Comment: you can use numbers in css classes but not as first character.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i have faced  the same problem.... actually it not a problem anyway..

instead of '.400-width' use '.width-400'

Answer (score 4):

this can help you with the semantic of css

[css semantic](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/)

## Bad Semantics

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="article_title">Smurf Movie Kinda Sucks</div>
  <div class="the_content">Not surprisingly, this weeks release of
     <div class="darkbold">The Smurfs</div> kinda sucks.</div>
</div>
```

## Good Semantics

```
<article>
  <h1>Smurf Movie Kinda Sucks</h1>
  <p>Not surprisingly, this weeks release of
     <b>The Smurfs</b> kinda sucks.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: The link may theoretically answer the question, but [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
.width-400{
    width:400px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS classnames can't begin with a number, they must begin with a letter; this has caught me out before when doing grid systems etc. You might use `width-400` or for brevity `w400`.

Answer (score 3):

```
._400-width{
    width:400px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) CSS identifier cannot start with number, but if you would like to keep `400-width`, you can use a little trick and replace leading number `n` with `\3n` like

```
.\34 00-width{
  width:400px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

Here you have it working [in your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzfwm0s/), plus few [other samples](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzfwm0s/),
and related [SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5672936/868184)