# Slider jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whats the problem with this script, it doesnt work. I've place the api's correctly

```
function Slider() {
  $(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
  $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

  var sc = $(".slider img").size();
  var count = 2;

  setInterval(function(){
    $(".slider #" +count).show("slide",{direction: 'right'}, 500);
    $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'}, 500);

    if(count == sc) {
      count = 1;
    }
        else {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }.6500);
}
```

Comment: whats the error? check firebug

Comment: you can't set a number as an ID, instead try `slider1`, `slider2`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number, ok you can, but it is not adviseable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo: replace `}.6500);` with `}, 6500);`