# I want the ID of the element as the background of the div

Tags: css, variables

I am trying to add a background image to each element on my page.
The background images name is same as the id of the page (without the.png)

for example:

```
<div class="ClassOne" id='1'> /* i want this to have a bg of:  background-image:url('1.png')*/
</div>
<div class="ClassOne" id='2'> /* i want this to have a bg of:  background-image:url('2.png')*/
</div>
<div class="ClassOne" id='3'> /* i want this to have a bg of:  background-image:url('3.png')*/
</div>
```

Comment: Check this for ids with numbers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with jQuery.

**Code Modified**

```
var element = $(".ClassOne");
for(var i=0; i<element.length; i++)
{
 var id = element.eq(i).attr("id");
 element.eq(i).css({
  "background": "url("+ id +".png)"
 });
}
```

Comment: element.eq(i).find(".statusbar").css({
  "background": "url(/img/waveform/"+ id +".png)"
 });
howcome this doesnt work? :(

Comment: http://beastdrops.com/test23.php and its Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: The waveform is appearing here.

Comment: look at the name of the waveform

Comment: Ok. Got it. Your divs are added dynamically. So the function here is unable to find the element in the DOM during the execution. Call this snippet after the divs are added i.e. on the click of your link when the dive is added, place this snippet after that.

Comment: I guess it is unable to find the element so it must have been undefined so the unexpected token.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a set number of possibilities? If you do you could use CSS:

```
#1 {
    background-image: url('1.png');
}
```

Now the element with an id of 1 will have that background image.

If you have multiple/more dynamic ids you might consider a javascript solution along the lines of: (edit: tailored to suit your comment)

```
function setBackgroundFromId(targetEl) {
    targetEl.style.backgroundImage('url(' + targetEl.id + '.png');
}
var imageDivs = document.querySelectorAll('ClassOne');
for (var i = 0; i < imageDivs.length; i++) {
    setBackgroundFromId(imageDivs[i]);
}
```

Comment: @KolosFeriFazekas Added a javascript solution which could be employed for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add the attribute:

```
style="background-image:url('x.png')"
```

To each element in the same way you generated the id attributes?

Comment: if only i could... im using soundmanager2 and it adds divs later... :(