# How do I turn cards over using onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently my cards are currently face down with the code* below. 
How would i go about changing them to face up using onClick functions? How would I then be able to use the ids to place in an Array and then use the IDs to get images from my images?

HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="0" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
    <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="1" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
    <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="2" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="3" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
   <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="4" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
   <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="5" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="6" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="7" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="8" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="9" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="10" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  <td><img src="cards_gif/b.gif" Class="back" id="11" onClick="flipCard()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
<style>
* {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-color: hsla(173,100%,50%,1.00);
    font-weight: bold;  
}

.back {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>
```

JS

```
function flipCard(theElementID){
    /*var cardID = ["c1","c2","c3"];""3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]; *//ignore
    var theElement.src = document.getElementById(theElementID);
    theElement.src ="c1.gif";
    document.getElementById(c1.gif")
} // don't really understand this function. I also tried using an array to pick the card image if that makes sense.
```

Comment: `onClick="flipCard(this.id)"` to pass the id to the function

Comment: You should change the IDs to not start with a number

Comment: Why not? @Huangism. What if I wanted to link it an an array with images? 
Example cards=["c1.gif"]
Is that possible?

Comment: @KoreyAbbott read the answer here carefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the onclick attribute which is needlessly repeated 12 times and wire a click event up to the image by css class in five lines of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.back').on('click', function() {
        flipCard(this.id); //Pass the img id to flipCard
    }); 
});
```

The original code has a few errors. See this fiddle which should give you some help: http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/gam8tcx7/2/

Comment: Would'nt it be better to wrap it inside an element with an ID and then bind the .on on that one like $('#element').on('click', '.back', function(){ });

Comment: You mean in the HTML markup? Edit: sorry didn't see your edit

Comment: Does'nt the way to do it bind on every element where mine will make one bind - not that it really matters that much

Comment: You'd have to repeat it for each element if you were to do it by ID.

Comment: It's syntax for the jQuery object, identical to using "jQuery". In JS names can include $ symbols.

Comment: Ah i've given up for today. I'll try again tomorrow but I doubt i'll get it.

Comment: See the fiddle I've added to my original answer. That should help you

Comment: Many thanks for your help @garryp i'm going to have a fiddle with my JavaScript and try and get it to work now. :)