# Get element id from class

Tags: jquery, selector

I have two elements with class "rate". The first element has id="1", and the second has id="2". When i use my selector :

```
    $(".rate").click(function()
    {
      var id=$(this).attr('id');
      alert(id);
      //Do something here
    }
```

I get answer = 1. How can i get the element with class="rate" and id = "2" ?

Comment: By clicking on the item with id = 2? Sorry, it's not clear why the code is in click handler.

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/Mwjvxa. Can you show the some HTML that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element, you can use `this`, as you already have

```
$(".rate").click(function()
{
  var element = $(this);
  //Do something here
});
```

If you want the ID, you seem to have forgotten to close off your code with a `);`

For me it works as such:
https://jsfiddle.net/jc1a402a/

---

Also, you shouldn't have ID's that start with a number:

See this question:
[can i have a div with id as number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number)

Comment: "See this question: can i have a div with id as number?" ... and its first, top-rated answer, beginning "yes, you can". :-)   A very-widely-supported misbehavior in older browsers, now validated by HTML5. Still looks weird to me, but not particularly dangerous.

Comment: It says 'Yes you can', but explains below that CSS selectors will give you a lot of trouble: "If you're going to use those ids [...] be aware that it can be a pain, because you can't use an id starting with a digit in a CSS id selector literally; you have to escape it."

Comment: Well, yes, except for that *completely valid and important* reason. I'd delete my comment if it wouldn't render yours nonsensical.