# JQuery - How to get the this for nested each

Tags: jquery

I have inner each like

```
$('a[id^="Page"]').each(function () {
   if ($(this).attr("id") == pageId) {
     $('[id="' + pageId + '"]"').each(function () {
       // code here
      });
  }
});
```

How to access the current element since `this` is from previous `each`?

Thanks!

Comment: cache `this` inside a var as `$this = this`

Comment: You don't need inner `each` as Identifiers must be unique and `this` is already referring to it? Can you share compete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the callback's second argument to get the element like so:

```
 $('a[id^="Page"]').each(function (index, element) {
         if ($(element).attr("id") == pageId) {
                  $('[id="' + pageId + '"]"').each(function (j, pageElment) {
                       console.log(element);
                       console.log(pageElment);
                  });
         }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the following callback signature to eliminate the use of `this`:

```
.each(function(outerIndex, outerElement) {
    .each(function(innerIndex, innerElement) {
        // Do stuff with outerElement...
    });
});
```

This is more readable than using `this` tautology.

However, in your example there is no need to use the second `each(...` inside your first `each(...` at all since you're looking for exact id. And if you know the `pageId` in advance - you don't need any `each(...`. Instead just use the id selector:

```
$('#' + pageId).// Do your stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` by default refers to the context that was calling the function. When you call `.each` on one or more elements, `this` will inside the function always refer to the current element.

Answer (score -1):

Just save `this` to variable and than you can use it:

```
$('a[id^="Page"]').each(function () {
     var $that = $(this);

     if ($that.attr("id") == pageId) {
          $('[id="' + pageId + '"]"').each(function () {
              console.log($that.data('val') === $(this).data('val'));
          });
     }
});
```

---

If you have your ID as number (E.g. `id="12345"`), than [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number)