# jQuery .on Event does not work with a variable selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create [on Click](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality for a dynamically loaded element. The ID of this element is in a variable `$element`. The ID is stored a string. I pass it to the `.on` event handler like this:

```
... .on("click", '"'+$element+'"', function() { ...
```

It doesn't work and gives out an error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#2"` (see [Case 1 JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wmf9tr9/)). `#2` is the ID of the element.

Then I tried wrapping it in a function like this:

```
... .on("click", function() {'"'+$element+'"'}, function() { ...
```

But it seems to turn the whole DOM into a clickable element (see [Case 2 JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqz8nmtb/)). Why...?

Finally, [Case 3 JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4ursy9r/) shows the behavior I want: if the user clicks the element with ID `#2`, something happens, if she clicks the element with ID `#3` or anywhere else, nothing happens. I just can't get it to work when the selector is passed as a variable.

---

[Case 1 JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wmf9tr9/) gives out a weird error.

[Case 2 JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqz8nmtb/) click "a" or "b" and "a" will turn red.

[Case 3 JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4ursy9r/) is what I am after. Click "a", it turns red, click "b" nothing happens.

Comment: you output `'"#2"'` as a string, which is invalid. additionally, ids should not start with numbers. just write: `.on("click", $element, function() { ...` since `$element` already is a string

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p4ursy9r/5/

Comment: @Alex https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute They can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your fiddle, [have a look at this](https://jsfiddle.net/p4ursy9r/5/):

```
var $element = '#a2';

$("#a1").on(
        "click",
        $element,       // <-- child Selector
        function() {
            $("#a1")
            .find('span')
            .filter(function() {
                return $(this).text() === 'a';
            })
            .css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    );
```

Please note that ids *should* not start with numbers, [at least in 4 times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5672939/1449710).

Comment: ids can start with numbers. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @epascarello i didnt say anything different :) i updated the answer though

Comment: I am laughing with a facepalm. Apparently just putting `$element` there works. IDs in my real code start with letters, I just simplified them in the example. I think I should leave the IDs in my question as is here so the answer carries an additional bit of information.

Comment: sure, there needs to be a string, so any variable of type string can be put there :) writing `'#2'` is the same as `$element`, when it is a string variable with that exact value :)