# jQuery - Get <p> text by variable ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
var itemCount = 0;
var addTo = "";

$(".add").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    var itemClicked = $(this).attr('id');
    var a = parseInt(itemClicked);
    alert($(".price").find('#' + a).text());
    itemCount = itemCount + 1;
  });
```

and

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3 class="item-header" id="1">iPhone</h3>
      <p>...</p>
      <p class="hidden" id="1">1</p>
      <p class="price" id="1">19.95</p>
      <p><button class="btn btn-primary add" role="button" id="1">Add to cart</button> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is write a function takes figures out which button triggered the function, and retrieves the according price to the button. In this case I pressed 1, and I want the price according to Item 1.

When I perform alert(a); then I retrieve the number of 1. So I suppose something is wrong with the following line, just cant figure out what...

```
alert($(".price").find('#' + a).text());
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: And ids can't start with a number

Comment: The .add element is in the button class, it retrieves the ID of the button which is one, and I'd like to use that ID to get the price according to ID="1"

Comment: @Stuart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number

Comment: I'm aware thanks @j08691 - it's never wise to do this, just because you can.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need id:

```js
$("button.add").click(function(){
  var $card = $(this).parents("div.caption");
  alert("adding good id:"+$card.children("input.good-id").val() + " with price: " + $card.children("p.price").text());
  /* note - don't send price to backend,
  it can be easily corrected in browser before click,
  send only id of the good, and get price from DB */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3 class="item-header">iPhone</h3>
      <p>...</p>
      <input type="hidden" class="good-id" name="goodId" value="1">
      <p class="price">19.95</p>
      <p><button class="btn btn-primary add" role="button">Add to cart</button> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a `data-price` attribute (or something to reference to your actual data). I don't think it's a good practice to be dependant on the value of some paragraph tags. Better is to have a separation of display data and internal data.

You can access the `data-price` like this:

```js
$('.button').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-price'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Shop</h1>
<p>iPhone 7</p>
<p>price € 110</p>
<button data-price="110" class="button">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your html markup to use data attributes. In that way it will be easier for you to select the needed prices of certain items:

```
<p class="hidden" data-item="1">1</p>
<p class="price" data-price="1">19.95</p>
```

Demo:

```js
$('.add').on('click', function() {
    var itemId = $(this).attr('id');
    var itemPrice = $('.price[data-price="'+ itemId +'"]').text();
    alert(itemPrice);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="item-header" id="1">iPhone</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <p class="hidden" data-item="1">1</p>
            <p class="price" data-price="1">19.95</p>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary add" role="button" id="1">Add to cart</button> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```