# Append array to a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array in javascript called `menuElm` that has `<ul>` elements in it:

```
<ul id="1"></ul>
<ul id="2"></ul>
<ul id="3"></ul>
```

I have a page in HTML that has the following:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"></li>
    <li class="menu-item"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add the elements of `menuElm` to the HTML page so it would look like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
         <ul id="1"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
         <ul id="2"></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
         <ul id="3"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the following, but the `<ul>` elements just wont show up in the page nor in the code:

```
function CreateMenu() {
    var menuElm;
    var k = 0;

    menuElm = createElm("ul");
    menuElm.id = ++k;

    for (var i = 0; i < menuElm.length; ++i) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item")[i].appendChild(menuElm[i]);
    }
}
```

I am new with JavaScript, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is best avoid using number as ID. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number)

Comment: You're declaring `var k = 0` in the function so `menuEl.id` will always be 1. Also it's unclear what `createElm("ul")` is returning, assuming it's a shortcut for `document.createElement()`.  But either way when `CreateMenu` run the loop is pretty useless as `menuElm` will always be a single element so not right to use `menuElm.length` in that case. You're better off saving the result of `document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item")` and loop over the length of that.

Comment: I changed `menuElm.length` to `3`, and added the `createElm("ul")` into the loop, which is doing the same as `document.creatElement("ul")` Now it is creating the 3 ul-s with different id-s as it should be, although it doesnt add it into the classes

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> menuElm.length
> ```

The `ul` element doesn't have a length, so you are looping from 0 to 0, which is 0 iterations.

---

> ```
> menuElm = createElm("ul");
> ```

This function isn't defined. You need `document.createElement('ul');`

---

> ```
> menuElm = createElm("ul");
> menuElm.id = ++k;
> ```

You appear to be creating one list item, and then changing its ID and appending it multiple times.

You need a new list item each time you go around the loop.

---

> ```
> appendChild(menuElm[i]);
> ```

You've been treating `menuElm` as an element previously. It isn't an array, `[i]` makes no sense here.

Comment: Also, `++k` is returning the value before incrementing, so you'd end up with 0 1 2 instead of 1 2 3 if this would have worked.

Comment: Nooooooooooo. NOOOOOOOO. not again with Quentin. Why do I keep failing while supporting ><.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu").find('li').each(function(i){
    $(this).append(menuElm[i]);
});
```

/* if you want to use jquery here is the code to append */