# My CSS doesn't affect the HTML code in a specific part?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML and CSS. I don't know where is the problem and why there is no effect.

```css
#1st_column {
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="1st_column">
  <h1 id="pop">
    POPULAR <br /> CLASSES
  </h1>
  <p>
    Why not give one of <br /> these popular classes<br /> a look?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: And what exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kUAnx/

Comment: ID's cannot start with a number.

Comment: Try using an ID which does not start with a digit, but with a letter.

Comment: @domdom the effect of background color and height and every style !!

Comment: @SuperUser — Since HTML 5, they can.

Comment: @Quentin -- html5 says that ids can begin with numbers but many browser doesn't support it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kUAnx/15/

Comment: Thanks all changing my ID to start without number solved the problem :)

Comment: ahmed, you might want to upvote and/or accept thebluefox's answer then.

Comment: @SuperUser — Not true. Browsers have no trouble with IDs starting with a number. See the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

ID's shouldn't start with a number, as it seems browser's don't fully support them yet.

```css
#first_column {
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first_column">
  <h1 id="pop">
    POPULAR <br /> CLASSES
  </h1>
  <p>
    Why not give one of <br /> these popular classes<br /> a look?
  </p>
</div>
```

**Edit**

To use ID's starting with a number, you can do so as shown in this answer;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5672936/19068

```
<div id="12"></div>

#\31\32 {
    background: #0bf;
}
```

Each number in the ID must be escaped using `\3`.

Personally, I wouldn't bother. It's ugly and just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: "ID's cannot start with a number" — Since HTML 5, they can.

Comment: *" browser's don't fully support them yet"* – Yes they do, if you use the correct CSS selector.

Comment: Fair point @JJJ

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

More info about it here : [can i have a div with id as number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number)

```css
#\31\st_column {
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="1st_column">
  <h1 id="pop">
    POPULAR <br /> CLASSES
  </h1>
  <p>
    Why not give one of <br /> these popular classes<br /> a look?
  </p>
</div>
```