# Wants to copy 3 input type value in single text area

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Suppose user Name is Rakesh Kumar Yadav, when he type name in 3 parts, I need to print value in singal textarea.
I am using This code
My english is bad.. But I think you were able to understand my issue.

```js
function setaddress() {
  var 1 = document.getElementById('1').value;
  var 2 = document.getElementById('2').value;
  var 3 = document.getElementById('3').value;

  document.getElementById('4').innerHTML = "S/O : " + 1 + ", " + 2 + ", " + 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="1" id="1" type="text" oninput="setaddress()">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Middle Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="2" id="2" type="text" oninput="setaddress()">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="3" id="3" type="text"  oninput="setaddress()">
</div>
<label>Complete Name</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="4" name="4" type="text" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing variable name` have you corrected this error in your code? As 0stone0 so accurately advised: the use of numeric characters as an `id` or variable is not advisable, the first character of variables should be alpha or underscore (`a-z` or `_`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Avoid starting an `id` with an Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-an-element-with-an-id-that-starts-with-a-number)
2. Avoid using Integers as variable name, `"S/O : " + 1` how does JS know the `1` is a variable, and not the number *one*?
3. The function is not called, I've added a button with a `onClick`

---

```js
function setaddress() {
  var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('c').value;

  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = "S/O : " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="1" id="a" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Middle Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="2" id="b" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="3" id="c" type="text">
</div>
<label>Complete Name</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="x" name="4" type="text" readonly></textarea>

<br />
<button onclick='setaddress()'>Update</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but need auto type text without clicking on update button

Comment: @RishabhThakur you can use onchange in each input fields and call that setaddress function onchange. Like this <input onchange="setaddress()" class="form-control" name="1" id="a" type="text">

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd like to offer a slightly different approach, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// I've camelCased the form, so that it's easier to read
// the name and understand the intent of the function;
// this is entirely a personal preference though so feel
// absolutely free to rename it to your own conventions
// and preferences:
function setAddress() {
  // here we use an Array-literal with the spread syntax
  // to assign the results of document.querySelectorAll()
  // to an Array, and for that Array to be assigned to the
  // variable of 'name':
  let name = [...document.querySelectorAll('.name')]
    // here we take the Array of .name elements and use
    // Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array based
    // on the Array of .name elements:
    .map(
      // 'el' is a reference to the current .name element
      // in the Array of elements, and we return the
      // trimmed value of the Array, using String.prototype.trim()
      // to remove leading/trailing white-space:
      (el) => el.value.trim()
    // here we filter the Array, with Array.prototype.filter():
    ).filter(
      // 'val' is a reference to the current Array-element,
      // which is the value of a .name element; if the
      // assessment - val.trim().length - results in a truthy
      // value (so the val after trimming has a length greater
      // than 0) we retain the value, otherwise it's discarded:
      (val) => val.trim().length
    );
  
  // here we find the element with the id of 'fullName', and we
  // update its value property to be equal to the Array of values
  // joined with a white-space character:
  document.querySelector('#fullName').value = name.join(' ');
}

// here we retrieve all <input> elements with a class-name of
// of '.name' and iterate over that collection using
// NodeList.prototype.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('input.name').forEach(
  // using an Arrow function to bind the setAddress() function
  // as the event-handler for the 'input' event (which handles
  // paste, keyup, keydown; any event which takes place in the
  // element that modifies the value):
  (el) => el.addEventListener('input', setAddress)
);
```

```css
:root {
  --commonSpacing: 1em;
  --flexBasis: 3;
}
form {
  display: grid;
  inline-size: clamp(20em, 60vw, 1000px);
  margin-block: var(--commonSpacing);
  margin-inline: auto;
}

form > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: var(--commonSpacing);
}

label {
  text-align: end;
  flex-basis: calc((100%/var(--flexBasis)) - 0.75em);
}

label::after {
  content: ':';
}

input {
  flex-basis: calc(2*(100%/var(--flexBasis)) - 0.75em);
}

div + label {
  text-align: start;
}

textarea {
  height: 5em;
  resize: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- I've chosen to wrap the various elements in a <form> in order
     that the various <input> elements and the <textarea> are
     semantically grouped: -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <!-- I've added a 'for' attribute which has an attribute-value
         equal to the 'id' of the related <input>, which allows a
         user to click on the <label> and focus the <input>; this
         is also useful for users with disabilities relying on the
         use of accessibility features to browse, navigate and use
         the internet:-->
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <!-- I've used meaningful, non-numeric id attributes in order
         for you to easily access the <input> elements via JavaScript: -->
    <input class="form-control name" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
    <input class="form-control name" name="middleName" id="middleName" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="fullName">Last Name</label>
    <input class="form-control name" name="familyName" id="familyName" type="text">
  </div>
  <label for="fullName">Complete Name</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="fullName" name="fullName" type="text" readonly></textarea>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/657wk8fq/).

It's important to remember that, as Mozilla notes in their reference documentation:

> **Note:** Technically, the value for an `id` attribute may contain any character, except [whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Whitespace) characters. However, to avoid inadvertent errors, only [ASCII](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/ASCII) letters, digits, '_', and '-' should be used and the value for an `id` attribute should start with a letter. For example, . has a special meaning in CSS (it acts as a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)). Unless you are careful to escape it in the CSS, it won't be recognized as part of the value of an `id` attribute. It is easy to forget to do this, resulting in bugs in your code that could be hard to detect. Citation: see reference for "`id` attribute", below.)

References:

- CSS:

  - [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content).
  - [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).
  - [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
  - [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
  - [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
  - [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
  - [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
  - [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
  - [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
  - [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
  - [`pseudo-elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
  - [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root).
  - [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
- HTML:

  - [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).
  - [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for).
  - [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).
  - [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).