# Problem querySelectorAll not recognising section name with number starting in name

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to retrieve a specific section from an html page using javascript (NodeJS)

```
document.querySelectorAll("section#sectionID")
```

It works fine with section names starting with letters. But one section name starts with a number like for example

```
section#4_someText_here
```

and I tried fetching it in a number of ways. The way it is suggested is I think this one

```
querySelectorAll("section#\\4 _someText_here")
```

But it doesn't find the section. Is this the correct way to use it?

Comment: Only letter, numbers, -, _ should be used, and an id should not start with a number.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id ... you can escape them though https://codepen.io/estelle/pen/jOvzbgb

Comment: @Ruskin thanks for the codepen. very helpful. yes I know I wouldn't use a number to start section id either, but thats what the website I am parsing is using. below answer is good with addressing this specific problem though.

Comment: Related: [Can I have an element with an ID that starts with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-an-element-with-an-id-that-starts-with-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors) with the `id` *attribute*:

```
document.querySelectorAll('section[id="4_someText_here"]');
```